# How do I get Yarn to flatten my TypeScript typings?

Tags: typescript, yarnpkg

I've installed both `@types/react` and `@types/react-dom`. Let's say they were at version 15 before, and that I then upgraded both using `yarn upgrade @types/react@16 @types/react-dom@16`.

`@types/react-dom` declares a dependency on `@types/react` using `"@types/react": "*"`, i.e. it should be able to work with the newly installed version. However, apparently Yarn has locked dependencies on `@types/react@*` to `@types/react@^15.0.22`.

The result of this is that `@types/react-dom` has its own copy of the React typings, still at v15 - due to which TypeScript starts to complain that I have duplicate type definitions.

What is the appropriate way to upgrade to v16 transitively? Can I avoid manually editing my `yarn.lock`?

Answer (score 0):

Note for if anyone comes across this in the future: the workaround I've used for now is to manually edit my `yarn.lock`:

```
-"@types/react@*", "@types/react@^15.0.22":
+"@types/react@^15.0.22":
  version "15.0.24"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@types/react/-/react-15.0.24.tgz#8a75299dc37906df327c18ca918bf97a55e7123b"

-"@types/react@^16":
+"@types/react@*", "@types/react@^16":
  version "16.0.9"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@types/react/-/react-16.0.9.tgz#2ad952abbb22617620927694f9a4bce292d7fb2b"
```

In other words, I indicate that dependencies pointed at `@types/react@*` should resolve to the same result as those that point to `@types/react@^16`.